# How to package, deploy, and manage scalable and reliable microservices and containers in Aws?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am searching for an option where i can package and deploy micro services in Aws same what we have in Azure as Service fabric. How can we achieve in Amazon AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an Azure Service Fabric cluster on AWS.
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/05/18/tutorial-how-to-create-a-service-fabric-standalone-cluster-with-aws-ec2-instances/

Comment: Thanks for the information! the above example show how to create a EC2 Inatnace(Windows VM) and then deploy Service cluster on it.I read somewhere that Lambda and Api are the two features in AWS which provide the  same functionality as Azure Service fabric.Do you have any idea how to we can achieve the same scenario in AWS?